# same docker-compose.yml file for two hosts on same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created docker-compose.yml file for my production environment and everything work great.

I installed a new different machine for staging and tried to use docker-compose up using the same yml configuration. I got lot's of errors from docker about "read/write" errors and more.

I assumed that the problem is that i am using the same service names on both hosts.

I prefer to keep using the same configuration file for easy maintenance.

i saw that there is an option to define different subnet for each docker and i will try to do it but i want to understand if its a very big "no no" to work like that? How can i have 2 different hosts on same subnet running same container configurations?

i am talking about two different hosts.

Comment: I do not think the errors you got is because of the servics names , please add the errors to the question

Comment: Maybe docker doesn't have permissions

Comment: @LinPy - I am not getting errors since i changed the subnet in the network section on Docker Desktop. But i feel that i am doing something wrong by using same service names and same network name on different hosts that located on the same physical network. Can someone explain if there is something?